# PHP return date in mmyy format up to a certain date

Tags: php, date

I'm looking to return a date up to and including the 5th of the following month as the current month, anything bigger than that will be output as the following month.

So for example:

If today is the **6th September 2015** the date will be returned as `1015`.

If today was the **5th September 2015** the date will be returned as `0915`.

If today was the **30th September 2015** the date will be returned as `1015`.

If today was the **29th August 2015** the date will be returned as `0915`.

If today was the **1st August 2015** the date will be returned as `0815`.

The date needs to be returned as `date('my')`

Comment: Can you add the code that you've used to attempt solving this?

Comment: I'm not sure how to address it so was looking for suggestions :)

Comment: Hate to sound like a teacher, but it's beneficial to move through the logic yourself first - if you run into some roadblocks, stack overflow-ers are more than happy to help!

Comment: That said, if you're not already familiar with it, the function [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and other date/time functions are going to be crucial in your logic - they translate dates to more workable units (like seconds) so you have a "common denominator", so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's date functions are insanely powerful. Have a look at http://php.net/strtotime sometime.

Here's the answer to your question:

```
$date = "6th September 2015";
echo date("my", strtotime($date ." +1 month -5 days")); // 1015
```